# Sympy solve looking for complex solutions, even if real=True?

Tags: python, sympy, solver, complex-numbers

I mean to solve a symbolic equation via `sympy.solve`.
It was taking surprisingly long, so I tried a few variations, until I found a posible cause.
It looks for complex solutions, while I am only interested in real solutions.

Code below...

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
x, y, z = sp.symbols('x, y, z', real=True, positive=True)

# Option X1: works
expr3 = 0.6*x**(9/8)*y**(7/5)*z**2.2
expr4 = 0.9*x**(1/2)*y**(4/5)*z**1.2
s3 = sp.solve(expr3 - expr4, x)
print('Exponents of x: 9/8, 1/2. Solution =', s3)

# Option X3: works
expr3 = 0.6*x**(11/9)*y**(7/5)
expr4 = 0.9*x**(1/2)*y**(4/5)
s3 = sp.solve(expr3 - expr4, x, check=True, minimal=True, rational=True, force=True)
print('Exponents of x: 11/9, 1/2. Solution =', s3)

# Option X2: takes "forever"
expr3 = 0.6*x**(11/9)*y**(7/5)
expr4 = 0.9*x**(1/2)*y**(4/5)
s3 = sp.solve(expr3 - expr4, x)
print('Exponents of x: 11/9, 1/2. Solution =', s3)
```

... produces this output

```
Exponents of x: 9/8, 1/2. Solution = [1.91313675093869/(y**(24/25)*z**(8/5)), 0.351080874270527*(-y**(-0.12)*z**(-0.2) - 0.726542528005361*I*y**(-0.12)*z**(-0.2))**8, 0.351080874270527*(-y**(-0.12)*z**(-0.2) + 0.726542528005361*I*y**(-0.12)*z**(-0.2))**8, 1.28055023108529*(0.324919696232906*y**(-0.12)*z**(-0.2) - I*y**(-0.12)*z**(-0.2))**8, 1.28055023108529*(0.324919696232906*y**(-0.12)*z**(-0.2) + I*y**(-0.12)*z**(-0.2))**8]
Exponents of x: 11/9, 1/2. Solution = [3*2**(8/13)*3**(5/13)/(4*y**(54/65)), (-2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*cos(pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)) - 2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*I*sin(pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)))**18, (-2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*cos(pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)) + 2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*I*sin(pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)))**18, (2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*cos(2*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)) - 2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*I*sin(2*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)))**18, (2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*cos(2*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)) + 2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*I*sin(2*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)))**18, (-2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*cos(3*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)) - 2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*I*sin(3*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)))**18, (-2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*cos(3*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)) + 2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*I*sin(3*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)))**18, (2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*cos(4*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)) - 2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*I*sin(4*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)))**18, (2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*cos(4*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)) + 2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*I*sin(4*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)))**18, (-2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*cos(5*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)) - 2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*I*sin(5*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)))**18, (-2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*cos(5*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)) + 2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*I*sin(5*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)))**18, (2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*cos(6*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)) - 2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*I*sin(6*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)))**18, (2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*cos(6*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)) + 2**(12/13)*3**(1/13)*I*sin(6*pi/13)/(2*y**(3/65)))**18]
```

from options X1, and X3, and then it is stuck at option X2. I have to manually interrupt calculation. 
X3 is one of many attempts at tinkering with options of `solve` to get a solution for X2.
From its result, I would understand why X2 takes so long.

The first element in the solution list is what I am looking for, possibly with later simplification.
My questions are as follows:

1. Q1: Why is `solve` looking for and returning complex solutions, if I set `real=True, positive=True`?
2. Q2: Even if not understanding Q1, is there any way to tell `solve` not to look for complex solutions? (Note: I also want `positive=True` for `x`, not `x=0`)
3. Q3: I would be ok with using options for `solve` that lead to calculations in reasonable time, even if I get complex solutions. 
   But how can I then automatically pick the real solution? 
   I would pick element 0, but I am not sure it will always be the correct one.

**Related**:

1. [Ignore imaginary roots in sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210704/ignore-imaginary-roots-in-sympy)
2. [Sympy very slow at solving equations using solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70405920/sympy-very-slow-at-solving-equations-using-solve)

Answer (score 2):

By default, `solve` converts floating point numbers in your expression into rational numbers, which then are used to solve some polynomial equation. When the computation takes a long time, we can play with keyword arguments. For the third case:

```py
expr3 = 0.6*x**(11/9)*y**(7/5)
expr4 = 0.9*x**(1/2)*y**(4/5)
s3 = sp.solve(expr3 - expr4, x, check=False)
print('Exponents of x: 11/9, 1/2. Solution =', s3)
```

The computation is immediate. Another option would be to ask `solve` to avoid converting floating point numbers to rational:

```py
s3 = sp.solve(expr3 - expr4, x, rational=False)
print('Exponents of x: 11/9, 1/2. Solution =', s3)
```

Again, the computation is really fast.

Now to the other question. One way to work around the issue might be by telling `solve` to only look for specific regions. The following commands takes a few seconds to compute:

```py
sp.solve([expr3 - expr4, x >= 0, y >= 0], x)
# [(1.75314834631487/y**(54/65),)]
```

However, note that the trivial solution x=0 is omitted.

Let's try on your first case:

```py
expr3 = 0.6*x**(9/8)*y**(7/5)*z**2.2
expr4 = 0.9*x**(1/2)*y**(4/5)*z**1.2
sp.solve([expr3 - expr4, x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0], x)
# [(1.91313675093869/(y**(24/25)*z**(8/5)),)]
```

Comment: Very useful answer +1.
Notes:
**1.** Using `[expr3 - expr4, x > 0, y > 0]` (I prefer `>` instead of `>=` for my needs) removed all solutions but the correct one, in case X1.
 So It might have answered Q2.
 But in case X3 it still leaves two of the complex solutions. So Q2 remains.
**2.** I am not sure Q1 and Q3 are answered either.
**3.** I did play before with `check` and `rational` options to get faster answers. Various combinations with `[expr3 - expr4, x > 0, y > 0]` produce strangely differing results.
**4.** I reorganized questions to make them clearer.

Comment: Your answer helped solving my problem, as of now. I posted an answer.
I still don't know the answer to Q1 and Q2.

Answer (score 1):

With rationals the last one runs faster:

```
In [45]: # Option X1: works
    ...: expr3 = Rational(3,5)*x**(Rational(9,8))*y**(Rational(7,5))
    ...: expr4 = Rational(9,10)*x**(Rational(1,2))*y**(Rational(4,5))
    ...: s3 = sp.solve(expr3 - expr4, x)

In [46]: print(s3)
[0, 3*2**(2/5)*3**(3/5)/(4*y**(24/25)), (-2**(4/5)*3**(1/5)/(8*y**(3/25)) + 2**(4/5)*3**(1/5)*sqrt(5)/(8*y**(3/25)) - 2**(4/5)*3**(1/5)*I*sqrt(sqrt(5)/8 + 5/8)/(2*y**(3/25)))**8, (-2**(4/5)*3**(1/5)/(8*y**(3/25)) + 2**(4/5)*3**(1/5)*sqrt(5)/(8*y**(3/25)) + 2**(4/5)*3**(1/5)*I*sqrt(sqrt(5)/8 + 5/8)/(2*y**(3/25)))**8, (-2**(4/5)*3**(1/5)*sqrt(5)/(8*y**(3/25)) - 2**(4/5)*3**(1/5)/(8*y**(3/25)) - 2**(4/5)*3**(1/5)*I*sqrt(5/8 - sqrt(5)/8)/(2*y**(3/25)))**8, (-2**(4/5)*3**(1/5)*sqrt(5)/(8*y**(3/25)) - 2**(4/5)*3**(1/5)/(8*y**(3/25)) + 2**(4/5)*3**(1/5)*I*sqrt(5/8 - sqrt(5)/8)/(2*y**(3/25)))**8]
```

Comment: I think this might not be an option for me. My `expr3` and `expr4` are the result of many calculations, in different functions. I would have to dig whether I can produce something with `Rational`. Unless I can convert those expressions themselves, and I don't know how.
If so, that *might* be a solution, and I would have to check if it works for my real cases (I put together an MCVE).
Besides your very interesting and useful finding, I would love to know answers for the questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer for Q1 and Q2.
But I managed to get code that gives me the single real positive solution that one would get by hand calculation for `expr3` and `expr4` of the same form as in the OP (`expr3 = number * product(xi**bi, i, 1, n)`, with `n` variables and exponents `bi` typically rational).
So far code worked for all use cases, including those that were not properly solved with any of what was posted.
And it works fast.

```
# Option X6: works
expr3 = 0.6*x**(4/9)*y**(1/3)
expr4 = 0.9*x**(2/5)*y**(2/5)
s3_allsoln = sp.solve([expr3 - expr4, x>0, y>0], x, check=False, minimal=True, rational=True, force=True, dict=True)
s3_real = [s3[x] for s3 in s3_allsoln if s3[x].is_real]
s3_realpos = [s3 for s3 in s3_real if s3.is_positive]
if(len(s3_realpos) != 1):
    print('Warning, found', len(s3_realpos), 'real positive solutions')
s3 = s3_realpos[0]
print('Exponents of x: 4/9, 2/5. Solution =', s3)
```

Output:

```
Exponents of x: 4/9, 2/5. Solution = 31381059609*sqrt(6)*y**(3/2)/8388608
```

I still need to simplify the numerical factor, into a decimal number.
But that is likely much easier.